# Time complexity of converting some elements of 2d array into 1d array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, radix-sort

I Am trying to implement Radix Sort in my own way.
I have successfully implemented it but i have a doubt that i may have altered the time complexity of the Sort by my Method .
so suppose i have a 1 d  array with 7 elements that i want to sort .
i have made a 2d array of size 7X10 (to be used as a bucket),
so this 2d will have a maximum of 7 non zero elements and the rest will be zero.
Now in my implementation  there comes a step in which i have to copy those non zero element from 2d array to my original 1d array
so i write its code as follows

Note: c is a index variable initialized to 0 and gets incremented

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
          {
              for(int j=0;j<bkt.length;j++)
              {
                  if(bkt[j][i]!=0)
                  {
                      ar[c]=bkt[j][i];
                      c++;
                  }
              }
          }
```

so does these nested loops change my time complexity ?
for time complexity will depend on the number of times the if condition gets trued ?

or let me make the question more easier , suppose i have a 2d array of nXn and say it has 10 non zero elements and rest at 0 and suppose i apply the similar step to copy the non zero elements of the array into a 1d array .
for will the time complexity of this step be n^2 as there are 2 for loops and the values of i and j are getting increased by just 1 only so all the elements needs to be scanned ??

Comment: I feel there are questions all over your paragraphs. Can you please write your final questions?

Comment: let me make the question more easier , suppose i have a 2d array of nXn and say it has 10 non zero elements and rest at 0 and suppose i apply the similar step to copy the non zero elements of the array into a 1d array . for will the time complexity of this step be n^2 as there are 2 for loops and the values of i and j are getting increased by just 1 only so all the elements needs to be scanned ??

Comment: If you iterate over `n^2` elements, then your time complexity is `O(n^2)`